# Are there any memory issues with this Eigen QR wrapper?

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix, eigen

I am writing a wrapper to Eigen QR for my personal use and I am wondering if there are any memory leaks or undocumented behavior in my implementation, especially in the function `get_QR()`.

The answer is as expected. This is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103526/weird-behavior-when-using-eigen).

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace Eigen;

/*!
 Obtains the QR decomposition as A=QR, where all the matrices are in Eigen MatrixXd format.
 */
void get_QR(MatrixXd A, MatrixXd& Q, MatrixXd& R) {

        int m           =       A.rows();
        int n           =       A.cols();
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);

        //      A_E     =       Q_E*R_E.
        HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A);
        Q  =   qr.householderQ()*(MatrixXd::Identity(m, minmn));
        R  =   qr.matrixQR().block(0, 0, minmn, n).triangularView<Upper>();
}

/*!
 Obtains the QR decomposition as A=QR, where all the matrices are in double format.
 */
void get_QR(double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R) {
        MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);

        //      Maps the double to MatrixXd.
        Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);

        get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

        Q       =       (double*)realloc(Q_E.data(), m*minmn*sizeof(double));
        R       =       (double*)realloc(R_E.data(), minmn*n*sizeof(double));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        srand(time(NULL));

        int m   =       atoi(argv[1]);
        int n   =       atoi(argv[2]);

//      Check the double version.
        int minmn       =       min(m,n);
        double* A       =       (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
        double* Q       =       (double*)malloc(m*minmn*sizeof(double));
        double* R       =       (double*)malloc(minmn*n*sizeof(double));

        double RANDMAX  =       double(RAND_MAX);
        //      Initialize A as a random matrix.
        for (int index=0; index<m*n; ++index) {
                A[index]        =       rand()/RANDMAX;
        }

        get_QR(A, m, n, Q, R);
        std::cout << Q[0] << std::endl;

//      Check the MatrixXd version.
        Map<MatrixXd> A_E(A, m, n);
        MatrixXd Q_E, R_E;
        get_QR(A_E, Q_E, R_E);

        cout << Q[0] << endl;
        cout << Q_E(0,0) << endl;

        free(A);
        free(Q);
        free(R);
}
```

For instance, I get the output as

> ```
> -0.360995
> -0.360995
> -0.360995
> ```

Comment: You mean apart from using `malloc` in C++ code?

Answer (score 6):

First check that there are the enough command line parameters

```
// If there are not enough parameters
//
// If there are no parameters passed then
// Then argv[1] is NULL
//      argv[2] is random
    int m   =       atoi(argv[1]);
    int n   =       atoi(argv[2]);
```

If not enough parameters are passed then this can get you funny number in `m` and `n` which will affect how much memory you allocate.

Don't use malloc in C++ code.
You can not mix malloc/free with new/delete. So by only using one system of memory management you will not mix up the two different types of memory.

```
    double* A       =       (double*)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));

   // Also the C++ interface is simpler.

    double* A       =       new double[m*n];
```

Secondly don't use pointer.
In modern C++ it is very rare to see RAW pointers (as they have no concept of ownership). And they are prone to leaking. you should be using either `smart pointers` or containers to hold your dynamically allocated memory.

In this case a container would have been better.

```
   std::vector<double> A(m*n);
```

All memory management now handled correctly.
This can then be used in your C code with

```
   double* Ap = &A[0];  // get the address of the first element.
```

This is not going to go well:

```
    Q       =       (double*)realloc(Q_E.data(), m*minmn*sizeof(double));

  // Q_E.data() better not only return you a pointer allocated with malloc.
  //            But it better set the internal pointers to NULL or some
  //            other safe value. As soon as the realloc() finishes the
  //            old pointer is no longer valid.
```

Also this is not the correct way to use realloc.

```
  size_t    size = /* Calc Size */;
  double*   data = (double*)malloc(size);
  ...
  size_t    newSiz = /* New Space needed */;
  double*   resize = (double*)realloc(data, newSize); 
  if (resize != NULL)
  {
      data = resize;  // if realloc() returns NULL the original array
      size = newSiz;  // is unaffected. You should check this after
  }                   // the call and only reassign the original
                      // value if the resize worked correctly.
```

Major Points:

I don't know what is happening inside `MatrixXd` but it looks like it is exposing its memory management outside the class. That is not a good idea. An object should know how to handle its memory in all situation (and do its own resizing as appropriate).

Two don't use RAW pointers (use C++ ownership symantics).

Learn the `Rule of Three/Five` so that objects manage their own memory.

Don't write C code and definately don't write C memory management code.

Comment: A reason why I do not want to use vector is it actually slows down the computation by a few factors. That is why I want to do all the memory management myself and also give the user some responsibility on the memory management front.

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner: I don't believe that. We have shown several times on SO that vector is as fast (and faster when you use realloc) than manual memory management. If there is a slow down then it is because you doing something non idiomatic and causing unnecessary copies. If you want to publish your version with std::vector we can show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Anyway fast and broken is not really as useful as slow and correct.

Answer (score 4):

@Loki Astari has hit on all the important points, but I have just a few things to add:

- Make sure you're including all of the libraries here, especially if someone wants to test this code.  You're missing `<iostream>`, `<ctime>`, and `<cstdlib>`.
- As Loki has mentioned, you're using a lot of C code in this C++ program.  Another instance of this is some of your casting.

  Instead of casting the C way (for this instance):

  ```
  double RANDMAX  =       double(RAND_MAX);
  ```

  cast the C++ way:

  ```
  double RANDMAX  =       static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX);
  ```
- Your use of whitespace for assignments is a little unusual.  Although it is okay to align a list of initialized variables (at least when you *must* have a list), I don't see the need in other instance such as this:

  ```
  for (int index=0; index<m*n; ++index) {
          A[index]        =       rand()/RANDMAX;
  }
  ```

  That makes the loop harder to read, and there's just no point to it.  In addition, you should also add a space between the operator and operands in the loop statement.

  You'll then have this:

  ```
  for (int index = 0; index < m*n; ++index) {
      A[index] = rand() / RANDMAX;
  }
  ```
- In `get_QR()`:

  ```
  void get_QR(double* A, int m, int n, double*& Q, double*& R) {}
  ```

  I'd group the arguments and parameters by types, making it less-likely to mismatch the arguments when making the function call.  Perhaps something like this:

  ```
  void get_QR(double* A, double*& Q, double*& R, int m, int n) {}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is any memory leak or undocumented behavior in my implementation

I don't see a leak, but it's difficult to confirm there isn't one.

This statement is dubious:

```
Q       =       (double*)realloc(Q_E.data(), m*minmn*sizeof(double));
```

If it had been this instead ...

```
Q       =       (double*)realloc(Q, m*minmn*sizeof(double));
```

... then it would have been less dubious; however if realloc fails it will return NULL, therefore overwriting a value with realloc can leak the previously-allocated value, so even that should be more like the following using a temp variable to test the result of realloc before using it to overwrite the previous value ...

```
double* temp       =       (double*)realloc(Q, m*minmn*sizeof(double));
if (!temp) {
    ... handle error here and don't forget to free Q ...
    return;
}
// else realloc successful
Q = temp;
```

However in your code I don't see how your get_QR function can be making use of the pre-allocated, passed-in `double* Q` and `double* R` arrays: and therefore I think that they're being leaked; maybe there wouldn't be a leak if you didn't allocate/initialize Q and R in main.

Depending on which compiler you're using, there may be built-in tools to detect memory leaks: e.g. [the Debug Heap for Microsoft's compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271695%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)); or for Linux I recommend using [valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).